# Testing eBike Lithium-Ion Battery

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

My wife has an e-scooter, which she's had for about 1 1/2 years.  Today she went to ride it and it died within a few minutes and it was, supposedly, fully charged.  When we plugged the charger in again, it started flashing red/green and now it just stays green.

I assumed the battery was the issue, but when testing it I'm getting confusing results.  The multimeter shows 25.5 volts, but shows nothing for resistance.  It doesn't show "0" or "OL", it just shows "1".  I've tested resistors, to ensure the multimeter is actually working and it is.  From what I've found, these results show that the battery has a short, but I'd like to confirm before taking apart the battery pack and testing each cell/connection.

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: DO NOT EVER try to measure the resistance of a battery (or any powered circuit).  An ohmmeter applies a voltage across its leads and measures the resulting current (or applies a current and measures the resulting voltage) to determine thet resistance.  If you try to measure a powered circuit, any reading you get will be meaningless.

Comment: '1' is commonly used as an over-range indication. The meter must have good quality protection circuits on the resistance range if it still works after applying 25 V to the inputs.

Comment: You have no evidence to suggest the battery has a short. You know enough to start fires, You do not know enough to repair batteries. Do not dismantle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multimeter's resistance measurement function applies a fixed voltage across the DUT (device under test) and measures the current or applies a fixed current and measures the voltage across the DUT. The second method is simpler as the resultant voltage can be fed to the display's ADC (analogue to digital convertor) and the voltage reading obtained displayed as ohms, kΩ, MΩ, etc. On the classic *"1999"* meters the display module will read 1999 at 199.9 mV (200 mV nominal) so all readings are electrically scaled to this range.

'1' is commonly used as an over-range indication. Your meter must have good quality protection circuits on the resistance range if it still works after applying 25 V to the inputs. Don't do this!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXb3gr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Measuring a battery's health.*

The correct way to measure the battery's health is to monitor the open-circuit voltage and then measure the voltage and current when under load. This allows calculation of the battery's internal resistance (which should be very low in a good battery).

Method:

- Measure the open-circuit voltage, V<sub>OC</sub>.
- Switch on the motor and measure the battery voltage, V<sub>L</sub>.
- Switch the multimeter to 10 A DC (amperes DC) range and plug the leads into the 10A and COM sockets (assuming a standard meter). Turn on the motor and measure the current, I<sub>L</sub>.
- You can now calculate the cell's internal resistance from
  $$ R_S = \frac {V_{OC}-V_L} {I_L} $$

Make it a habit to move the red lead back to the VΩmA socket when finished taking the high-current reading. This reduces the likelihood that you will try to take a voltage reading with a meter configured for current as this would apply a very low resistance across the circuit being measured and could destroy the meter, cause it to explode - many of the cheaper ones have no fuse protection on the 10 A range - and cause direct or indirect injury.